# Get number of table under a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have unknown number of `tables` under a `div`

How can I count many `table` there are under that `div` in either plain JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: I fixed the text of your question, now please post an example of your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var particularDiv = document.getElementById('particularDiv');

var  allTables = particularDiv.getElementsByTagName('table').length;
```

You can get the particular div and get table tags under that div by using pure javascript like above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length`:

```
var numberOfTables = $('div#yourDivId table').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("table", "#your-div-id").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, if you are willing to use jquery:

```
$("#yourdiv").find("table").length
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
var tableCount = $('#myDiv table').length;
```